# spring security - time based URL with authentication token

Tags: spring, spring-security

I need to implement user authentication where the following:

1. user gets a link, on the link there's a token that encrypts some of his details (id etc) and expiration time ==> this URL is outside of my application and already implemented
2. when user clicks on link, I need to decrypt the token and parse the data, but I don't need to compare it with the data in DB. Only to check the time didn't expire and fetch the data (id etc) out

Can you please guide me on which classes to use? I've been reading a lot, for now I think I need to extend AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter to grab the token from the URL and decrypt it, but I'm not sure about the authentication provider, and if I need a userService implementation?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I've been reading more and now I'm not sure I need the PreAuthenticated classes since it's not like the user was previously authenticated, I still need to authenticate him. The authentications is actually seeing that decryption works and that expiration time hasn't been reached. What do you suggest? I started to write my own filter (extending AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter), then I saw I need my own AuthenticationToken implementation since the UsernamePasswordAuthentication doesn't fit for me, then also in the provider I couldn't find really something that fits.

Any help would be appriciated. I'm considering just extending AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter but not use an authentication manager since it just gets me more complicated. What do you think?

Comment: Do you need to load some roles from DB? Do you use default user schema?

Comment: no, I don't need any roles or fetch anything from the DB. All the info I need exists inside the encrypted token on the URL. I'm not sure I understand the second question about the user schema..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach you could use:

1) Extend 'GenericFilterBean' to create your own security filter that you can then use as a 'custom-filter' in yout 'http' configuration.

2) Optional: Based on your needs you could implement your own 'UserDetails' which is very straightforward.

3) Optional: You could use "PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken" for your 'Authentication' implementation.

4) In the filter you could look for presence of the appropriate params, try to decrypt information. In case of any problem throw an Authentication Exception and handle it in the entry point described next.

5) Optional: In case of success you could wrap your UserDetails object in PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken and set it to the security context holder.

6) Implement "AuthenticationEntryPoint" and override "commence" to clear securitycontext/session, handle AuthenticationException from your custom filter and/or redirect/dispatch to a view. Use this as your entry point.